# Block incoming traffic to the specified IP behind the router

Tags: connection, blocking, firewall, rtmp

My goal is to emulate network disconnection for a video streaming server behind the router in LAN network. The only restriction which i have that this settings could not be executed on video server directly because i have not permissions to access it, and except this, i do not want to use router settings to be changed.
   I have another PC behind the router which i want to use to approach this. Perfectly, if there is a way to run on my another PC some tool or firewall programme which could the below:

1. Block incoming traffic to the specified IP address (in my case - for video server), except traffic on several ports for some external IP.
   The idea of this, that my video server shouldn't get any incoming connections except connection for some external IP on several ports.
2. Block outgoing traffic to the specified IP address except rtmp and rtmpt (1935, 80 ports).
   The idea of this, that my video server shouldn't send any else instead of traffic on rtmp or rtmpt protocols (1935, 80 ports).

How could i accomplish this? Which kind of tool could help? Is there a way to do it using windows batch scripting or linux shell scripting on PC?

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic use for a firewall - allowing policies to be created regarding the source, destination and ports being requested.  There are some great opensource options here.

It is true that some routers do offer this functionality too - so you may be in luck if you have a managed layer 3 router.

Beyond that - you may be able to to enforce the rules on your PC - Linux offers IPTables.

The down side is the further into your stack you allow the request to flow the more resources it is using.

Comment: ok, but actually, i want to achieve this on windows, so next opinion regarding my question i left here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21859647/1643018)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iptables under Linux, they're really powerful.

Here is a starting tutorial - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/

Comment: is there something for windows without gui?

Comment: yes, netsh advfirewall - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: answered my opinion here, but not sure... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21859647/1643018)